# Elementor Widget Sepparation problems

Tags: wordpress, web, elementor

I'm using elementor for the first time and I can't remove the space between widgets, you can see the small line of 8px in gray colour with a gradient inside (thats my picture). When I put this picture Elementor adds the white space above and below the line, I thought this is added only at desing time but when I update and see in the browser the whites spaces continues here. Of course the picture in the media gallery don't have this white spaces... I don't know what to try, the only trick is to force the margins but then when the screen changes it's overlapped (this is not a solution). I think Elementor should place the picture without nay margin, only the picture. I have the next properties set:

```
 Content: Full Width
 Elementor Widgets Space: 0px
 Columns Gap: no gap 
 All margins and paddings: none (0px)
 Tried height to default and forced to 8px
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas that might help you:

- check for a border, maybe you set it on accident or it got imported
- take a look at your custom css. Sometimes plugins like envato elements add their custom css without you noticing

It's also a good idea to use your browser and inspect the element to find out if there is any gap. You can also try that on the elements next to the widget you are using.

Comment: I think is the Elementor Widget Space because the extra sepparation is 20px, like the elementor default widget space, but, I set it to zero in the general settings and in the page settings... I think it's a bug.